# Using aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration for multiple cors_rules with terraform aws provider version 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In aws provider version 3, we defined the cors_rule in the aws_s3_bucket resource like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  ...

  dynamic "cors_rule" {
    for_each = var.cors_rule
    content {
      allowed_headers = lookup(cors_rule.value, "allowed_headers", [])
      allowed_methods = lookup(cors_rule.value, "allowed_methods", [])
      allowed_origins = lookup(cors_rule.value, "allowed_origins", [])
      expose_headers  = lookup(cors_rule.value, "expose_headers", [])
      max_age_seconds = lookup(cors_rule.value, "max_age_seconds", null)
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

That way, when we call the module, we can define several cors rules, and this resource would create them all.

We have tried many different ways to do this in version 4, and nothing is working.

How can we achieve this same outcome with the new aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration in version 4?

Comment: It doesn't work with `for_each` for the `aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration` resource?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is it can't be dynamic since it's a required parameter in the new provider version.

Comment: "nothing is working" - is not specific. Provide exact details of "not working"? Any errors?

Comment: it would take up too much space to show everything I have tried

Answer (score 1):

It's a resource it will always be created by default but it requires those values to be created. The only way I could solve this is to conditionally create it and add the values.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration" "default" {
  count = local.enabled && var.cors_rule_inputs != null ? 1 : 0

  bucket = join("", aws_s3_bucket.default.*.id)

  dynamic "cors_rule" {
    for_each = var.cors_rule_inputs

    content {
      allowed_headers = cors_rule.value.allowed_headers
      allowed_methods = cors_rule.value.allowed_methods
      allowed_origins = cors_rule.value.allowed_origins
      expose_headers  = cors_rule.value.expose_headers
      max_age_seconds = cors_rule.value.max_age_seconds
    }
  }
}
```